# How many paths does a square have from bottom left to top right?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider the graph $G=(V=\{0,...,n\}^2, E=\{ e\subseteq V \mid |e|=2, \forall v,w\in e: ||v-w||_2\leq 1\})$, $n\in\mathbb N$. How many paths connecting $(0,0)$ and $(n,n)$ are there? This seems to become quite complex when trying to look at it as a sequence of symbols which indicate directions to go in and counting them since we can have circles. I haven't come to a better idea however.

Comment: Presumably you restrict these paths to not revisit any vertex?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Is it possible to express the rules in words?

Comment: Just checking on the paths, the reference to circles made me ask. And to be clear, this is a finite square [lattice graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph)?

Comment: Yes, this is a square grid graph.

Comment: By circle I meant that one can go down and to the left. This is of course not really circle but it resembles a turn which reminded me of a circle.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A007764 which was found by finding the first three terms in the sequence (1,2,12) by inspection and then [searching oeis](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C12+path&sort=&language=english&go=Search) with the additional word "path."

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be an open problem after all. This paper https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506341 is all I could gather from the link.